# In how many sequences $n$ terms long does $x$ appear?

Tags: combinatorics

How many sequences $n$ terms long exist where each term is a number from $0$-$9$, and a specific number, let’s say $x$, is present anywhere in the sequence.

I thought to solve this by taking all the possible sequences, $10^n$, and subtracting from it the sequences where $x$ is not present, meaning $9^n$.

Is this correct?

So for a sequence $2$ terms long, there are $19$ sequences where the number $2$ appears.

Comment: This question is nearly equivalent to asking *How many $n$-digit numbers have $x$ in them?* That said, your solution seems correct.

Comment: Your solution is correct.